# VBA seems to disappear after I protect a range of cells

Tags: vba, locking, cells

Hi I can't seem to get my head around this problem:

After I lock a range of cells A1:U1 (and all other cells are unlocked) and I then protect the worksheet - the VBA in the worksheet doesn't appear to work anymore - is there any way around this??

Thanks,
Kieran

Comment: What do you mean by 'the worksheet doesn't appear to work'?

Answer (score 0):

If the VBA changes cells that you have locked then you need to update the VBA to unlock the worksheet before running the rest of the code. Then complete the Sub by locking the worksheet.

```
'Add to beginning of the Sub

    Sheets("worksheet_name").Unprotect Password:="password"

'Add to end of the Sub

    Sheets("worksheet_name").Protect Password:="password"
```